# Bash broken pipe with tcpdump

Tags: bash, shell, xargs, tcpdump, piping

I use the following command to send pinging IP's to a script:

```
sudo tcpdump -ne -l -i eth0 icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo \
  | cut -d " " -f 10 | xargs -L2 ./pong.sh
```

Unfortunately this gives me:

`tcpdump: Unable to write output: Broken pipe`

---

To dissect my commands:

- Output the ping's from the traffic:

  `sudo tcpdump -ne -l -i eth0 icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo`

  Output:

  `11:55:58.812177 IP xxxxxxx > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 50776, seq 761, length 64`
- This will get the IP's from the tcpdump output:

  `cut -d " " -f 10 # output: 127.0.0.1`
- Get the output to the script:

  `xargs -L2 ./pong.sh`

  This will mimic the following example command:

  `./pong.sh 127.0.0.1`

---

**The strange thing is that the commands work seperate (on their own)...**

I tried debugging it but I have no experience with debugging pipes. I checked the commands but they seem fine.

Comment: Please make sure: `pong.sh` must be in the current directory and executable.

Comment: I made sure it is. Thanks for double checking.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that's `cut` stdio buffering is interfering here, i.e. replace `| xargs ...` by `| cat` in your cmdline to find out.

Fwiw below cmdline *wfm* (pipe straight to `xargs` then use the shell itself to get the *nth* arg), note btw the extra `tcpdump` args : `-c10` (just to limit to 10pkts, then show the 10/2 lines) and `-Q in` (only inbound pkts):

```
$ sudo tcpdump -c 10 -Q in -ne -l -i eth0 icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo 2>/dev/null | \
  xargs -L2 sh -c 'echo -n "$9: "; ping -nqc1 $9 | grep rtt' 
192.168.100.132: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.743/3.743/3.743/0.000 ms
192.168.100.132: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.863/5.863/5.863/0.000 ms
192.168.100.132: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.167/6.167/6.167/0.000 ms
192.168.100.132: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.256/4.256/4.256/0.000 ms
192.168.100.132: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.545/1.545/1.545/0.000 ms
$ _
```

Comment: Got a similar issue with piping tcpdump output. Where `tcpdump | myscript` would fail, `tcpdump | cat | myscript` works. So, thanks for that. But why ?

Answer (score 0):

For those coming across this (like me), tcpdump buffering is the issue.
From the man page:

```
 -l        Make stdout line buffered.  Useful if you want to see the data
           while capturing it.  For example:

                 # tcpdump -l | tee dat
           or
                 # tcpdump -l > dat & tail -f dat
```